# Merge two files, line by line, after matching pattern in a new line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I need merge 2 files if there is ona match. The match in not static is random but is always after one specific tag

File 1

```
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-03" site_id="xxx.com" xmltv_id="xxx@com">xxx@com</can>
```

File 2

```
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 01">xxx 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 02">xxx 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 03">xxx 03</can>
```

I need make the file number 3 like this

```
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-03" site_id="xxx.com" xmltv_id="xxx@com">xxx@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 01">xxx 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 02">xxx 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 03">xxx 03</can>
```

I hope is clear, if the tag inside the file 1 "site_id=" match with the tag "same_as=" inside the file 2, I need merge the data.

Honestly I have no idea what I can do to have this result, I checked many posts but all merge data on the same line, I can't find something merge data on new line.

I like if is possible use sed or awk but every suggestion is welcome.

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1):

assumes file2 is sorted by the key

```
$ awk -F' |=' 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=="site_id") {a[$(i+1)]=$0; break}; next} 
                       {k=""; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i=="same_as") {k=$(i+1); break}
                        if(!p[k]++) print a[k]}1' file1 file2

<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-03" site_id="xxx.com" xmltv_id="xxx@com">xxx@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 01">xxx 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 02">xxx 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 03">xxx 03</can>
```

ps. this should be dramatically faster than other solutions for large files.

Comment: Your solution also is working really well! Thank you about your answer. To say thank my proposal is always valid, if you are near Milano one pincher of beer is avalable for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Read a file line by line, find URL and search for it in a second file.

```
while read -r line; do
        echo "$line" >> file3
        url=$(sed 's/.*site_id="\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/' <<< $line)
        grep $url file2 >> file3
done < file1

$ cat file3
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-03" site_id="xxx.com" xmltv_id="xxx@com">xxx@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 01">xxx 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 02">xxx 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 03">xxx 03</can>
```

Comment: I try, really thank you about your help, you have one pincher of beer paid when you will be in Milano!

Comment: @Tapiocapioca I'm in middle of Siberia, but I hope to be there sometimes :)

Comment: I hope I can visit Siberia with my girlfriend :) But maybe you prefer vodka :P

I is working but ignore the last match. What's can be?
My result is:

<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you know for sure these formats are consistent and always on a single line...

```
$: cat c $ file 1 is a, file 2 is b
#! /bin/env bash

while read -r line
do pat="${line##* site_id=\"}"
   pat="${pat%%\"*}"
   echo "$line"
   grep " same_as=[\"]$pat[\"] " b
done < a

$: c
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-01" site_id="foo.com" xmltv_id="foo@com">foo@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 01">foo 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="foo.com" id="foo 02">foo 02</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-02" site_id="bar.com" xmltv_id="bar@com">bar@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="bar.com" id="bar 01">bar 01</can>
<can update="x" site="merge-xml-03" site_id="xxx.com" xmltv_id="xxx@com">xxx@com</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 01">xxx 01</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 02">xxx 02</can>
<can offset="u" same_as="xxx.com" id="xxx 03">xxx 03</can>
```

Comment: One pincher of beer is wating you if you will be in Milano :)

Comment: Yes your script also is working really well but have the same problem of the other guy, ignore and doesn't save the last match, I can bypass this trouble adding one fake line at the end, but is strage... I am using one subsystem linux under windows.... Maybe it is the problem..

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline to understand why you need a `\n` at the end of the last line

Comment: Don't worry, I know about, I use the tool dos2unix before run every script ;)

Comment: Huh. I explicitly removed the newline and confirmed it's gone, and expected it to fail the same for me but it doesn't. Which version of grep are you using? `grep (GNU grep) 3.0` here.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*same_as=\("[^"]*"\).*#/site_id=\1/a&#' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Turn file2 into a sed script that appends each line on matching the value of the `same_as` with file1's `site_id`. Then pipe the generated script through to a second invocation of sed which is run against file1. Each time a line from file1 is read in, lines from file2 are appended in sequence to it.

To delete lines from file1 which do not have a match in file2, use:

```
sed -e 's#.*same_as=\("[^"]*"\).*#/site_id=\1/{a&\nx;s/^/x/;x}#' file2 |
sed -f - -e 'x;/x/{z;x;b};d' file1
```

This adds a flag in the hold space which is set when a line from file2 is added and when it is not set, to delete the current record from file1

Comment: Really thank you about you help, also your seggestion is working really well! :) :)

Comment: I want ask you, is possible DON'T join the first file, if there isn't the match? In this way all lines from the first file are joined but I can't use them without the second line.

Comment: Also for you one pinch of beer and pizza paid in Milano :)